# Adding input variables to plot title/legend in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, text, legend

I would like to display the current value of a parameter used to plot a certain function in the plot title/legend/annotated text. As a simple example, let's take a straight line:

```
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def line(m,c):
   x = numpy.linspace(0,1)
   y = m*x+c
   plt.plot(x,y)
   plt.text(0.1, 2.8, "The gradient is" *the current m-value should go here*)
   plt.show()

print line(1.0, 2.0)
```

In this case, I would like my text to say "The gradient is 1.0", but I'm not sure what the syntax is. Moreover, how would I include the second (and more) parameter(s) below, so that it reads:

"The gradient is 1.0

The intercept is 2.0."

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use string formatting with the `.format()` method:

```
plt.text(0.1, 2.8, "The gradient is {}, the intercept is {}".format(m, c))
```

Where `m` and `c` are the variables you want to substitute in.

You can directly write the variables like this in *Python 3.6+* if you prefix the string with an `f` whcih denotes a formatted string literal:

```
f"the gradient is {m}, the intercept is {c}"
```

Answer (score 3):

In python 3.6+ you can do it by prefixing the string with `f`, and putting the variable in curly brackets. For earlier python version there have been various ways of doing it, look up *string formatting*

```
message = f"The slope is {m}"
plt.text(message)
```

(by the way, *gradient* is usually called *slope* when referring to single variable linear equation)

Answer (score 0):

The other answers didn't work for my code, but adaption of it did. Shown below:

Showing y = m*x + c printed on the plot in log format.

```
a1 = coefs[0] # variable 1
a2 = coefs[1] # variable 2

message = f"log(L/Lo) = {a1} * log(M/Mo) + {a2}"

# Define axes
left = 0.01
width = 0.9
bottom  = 0.01
height = 0.9
right = left + width
top = bottom + height
ax = plt.gca()

# Transform axes
ax.set_transform(ax.transAxes)

# Define text
ax.text(0.5 * (left + right), 0.5 * (bottom + top), message,
        horizontalalignment='center',
        verticalalignment='center',
        size= 10,
        color='r',
        transform=ax.transAxes)

plt.show()
```

Using code from @ https://pythonguides.com/add-text-to-plot-matplotlib/

[image]