# Matplotlib: legend entries with variables

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I am a beginner in python, so apologies if this is a very basic question. I want legend entries to be shown dependent on input variables. I already searched for a solution, but none of the tutorials on legends seem to cover what I want to achieve. The closest match was [this other solution for plt.text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51812323/adding-input-variables-to-plot-title-legend-in-python) which works fine, but does not work for legend entries, see my code example below.

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

input_var1 = 4
input_var2 = 3

y1 = np.random.rand(10)
y2 = np.random.rand(10)
x = np.linspace(0, 9, 10)

plt.plot(x, y1)
plt.plot(x, y2)

# Neither
plt.legend("Plot with input = {}".format(input_var1))
# nor
plt.legend(f"Plot with input = {input_var1}")
# works

# but this works:
plt.text(2, 0.2, "Some text with variable = {}".format(input_var1))    

plt.show()
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without bothering to create a legend, variable support is possible by specifying the label of the plot, so it can be achieved by setting it and calling plt.legend().

```
plt.plot(x, y1, label="Plot with input = {}".format(input_var1))
plt.plot(x, y2, label="Plot with input = {}".format(input_var2))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I failed to mention that I also tried your approach. In this case, I simply didn't know I still had to call plt.legend(). If I could mark both answers as accepted answers, I would do it.

Comment: My answer is the basic form, and I'll use @jf_'s example for customizing it.

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass an iterable to `legend`, and as you have two plots, pass two legend entries:

```
plt.legend(["First data with {}".format(input_var1),"Second data with {}".format(input_var2)])
```

Plots this:
`[image]

Comment: Thank you! Yes, I shortened my line with the legend input for readability, shouldn't have done it. The core error was the missing square brackets.

Answer (score 2):

This also works for me:

```
str1 = 'Plot with input =' + str(input_var1)
str2 = 'Plot with input =' + str(input_var2)
plt.legend([str1,str2])
```